# data analytics; webscraping a website for its data with python and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Alright, basically the webpapge contains some data on breach events that happened and i need the events and date.

my code although not finished does not seem to work and I'm not an expert so I can't debug it.

Someone said it might be javascript heavy but i don't have a clue what that means. This project would get me more marks for my dissertation so i need it to work.

error:

> 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'   File
> "/Users/hazael/WEBSCRAPE/test.py", line 19, in 
> event_containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='frst-timeline-content-inner']")
> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute
> 'find_elements_by_xpath'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Set path to chromedriver executable
webdriver_service = Service('/path/to/chromedriver')

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

# Set the implicit wait time to 10 seconds
driver.set_page_load_timeout(100)

# Open the webpage
url = 'https://carnegieendowment.org/specialprojects/protectingfinancialstability/timeline'
driver.get(url)

# Find all the event containers on the webpage
event_containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='frst-timeline-content-inner']")

# Extract the event names from each event container
event_names = [container.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text for container in event_containers]

# Print the event names
for event_name in event_names:
    print(f"Event Name: {event_name}")

# Find the learn more button
learn_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-more-label="Learn More"]')

# Check if the learn more button is visible
if learn_more_button.is_displayed():
    # Click on the learn more button
    learn_more_button.click()
else:
    print("The learn more button is not visible")
```

Comment: I think there is no ***find_elements_by_xpath*** method, and you should use `find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='frst-timeline-content-inner']")`. Look at the documentation [selinium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the data into a pandas dataframe using `requests`/`beautifulsoup`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://carnegieendowment.org/specialprojects/protectingfinancialstability/timeline"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0"
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for block in soup.select(
    "#timeline-start [data-animation]:not(:has([data-animation])):has(h2)"
):
    name, date, desc = (
        block.h2.text,
        block.find(class_="frst-date").text
        + " "
        + block.find_previous(class_="frst-labels").text,
        block.p.text,
    )
    data = {h4.text: h4.find_next("p").text for h4 in block.select("h4")}

    all_data.append({"name": name, "date": date, "short desc": desc, **data})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                           name               date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   short desc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Target                                                                      Incident                                                         Actor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Description
0                                          Beanstalk Farms cryptocurrency theft      April 17 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           On April 17, 2022, the decentralised finance platform Beanstalk Farms lost $180 million in a cryptocurrency heist.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Location: United States\nDate Breach First Reported: 4/18/2022                                                   Method: Other \nType: Theft                           Type: Unknown\nAttribution: Unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  On April 17, 2022, the decentralised finance platform Beanstalk Farms lost $180 million in a cryptocurrency heist. The attackers took out a large enough loan to acquire enough voting rights to make the necessary governance changes to move all of Beanstalk’s reserves. The price of each Bean has since plumeted to near zero before coming back up to around one dollar. \n
1                                                      Fakecalls banking trojan      April 11 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                On April 11, 2022, researchers reported on the banking trojan Fakecalls, which has the ability to ‘talk’ to victims and pretend to be a employee of the bank.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Location: South Korea\nDate Breach First Reported: 4/11/2022                                              Method: Malware \nType: Multiple                           Type: Unknown\nAttribution: Unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             On April 11, 2022, researchers reported on the banking trojan Fakecalls, which has the ability to ‘talk’ to victims and pretend to be a employee of the bank. Fakecalls mimics the mobile apps of popular Korean-based banks. The trojan seeks to gain access to the victims contacts, microphone, camera, location and call handling, and attackers attempt to gain payment data or confidential information from the victim. Fakecalls also has a spyware toolkit.\n
2                                                          CashMama data breach       April 6 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        On April 6, 2022, India-based loans app CashMama reported a data breach, in which customer data that was invasively collected and stored was exposed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Location: India\nDate Breach First Reported: 4/6/2022                                             Method: Other \nType: Data breach                           Type: Unknown\nAttribution: Unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               On April 6, 2022, India-based loans app CashMama reported a data breach, in which customer data that was invasively collected and stored was exposed. CashMama’s Amazon S3 bucket was left in open form, which exposed customers’ personal data and other sensitive information.\n\n
3                              Lazarus  ‘Trojanised’ decentralised finance app        April 1 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                On April 1, 2022, North Korean state-sponsored threat group Lazarus was found to be using ‘Trojanised’ decentralised finance apps to deliver malware in their latest spearphishing campaign.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Location: Multiple\nDate Breach First Reported: 4/1/2022                                              Method: Malware \nType: Multiple     Type: State-sponsored actor\nAttribution: High confidence                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       On April 1, 2022, North Korean state-sponsored threat group Lazarus was found to be using ‘Trojanised’ decentralised finance apps to deliver malware in their latest spearphishing campaign. The malware is a full-featured backdoor containing sufficient capabilities to control the compromised victim.\n
4                                                    Ronin cryptocurrency theft      March 23 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                On March 23 2022, blockchain project Ronin lost $615 million in ether and USD Coin tokens in the second largest cryptocurrency heist to date.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Location: Canada\nDate Breach First Reported: 3/29/2022                                                   Method: Other \nType: Theft     Type: State-sponsored actor\nAttribution: High confidence                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      On March 23 2022, blockchain project Ronin lost $615 million in ether and USD Coin tokens in the second largest cryptocurrency heist to date. Hackers exploited a feature allowing users to transfer their digital assets from crypto network to another. Ronin is used to power the popular online blockchain game Axie Infinity. The US subsequently attributed the incident to North Korean state-backed hacking collective Lazarus Group and announced new sanctions against an ethereum wallet belonging to the group.\n
5                                                     TransUnion SA data breach      March 17 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Credit bureau TransUnion SA suffered a cyber attack which saw around three million customer's data stolen by a criminal third party.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Location: South Africa\nDate Breach First Reported: 3/17/2022                                           Method: Malware \nType: Data breach                           Type: Unknown\nAttribution: Unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Credit bureau TransUnion SA suffered a cyber attack which saw around three million customer's data stolen by a criminal third party. The attackers demanded a ransom but TransUnion refused to pay.\n


...and so on.
```